# How to have one element showing on page load when using a script that shows div onclick of link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that will show on click of a link, but I need the first element to be showing when the page loads. Right now, it is just a blank space.
Also, the page scrolls to the div and makes it be at the top of the page, how do i prevent that from happening?

Here is the html,

```
<a href="#expe1" class="fa fa fa-times closer" >Link1</a>  
<div class="resume" id="expe1">Open Block 1</div> 

<a href="#expe2" class="fa fa fa-times closer" >Link2</a>  
<div class="resume" id="expe2">Open Block 2</div>  

<a href="#expe3" class="fa fa fa-times closer" >Link3</a>  
<div class="resume" id="expe3">Open Block 3</div> here
```

and here is the javascript

```
$('.resume') .hide()
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
$('.resume') .hide()
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    $('.resume'+target).toggle();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `.show()` in your JQuery like this

```
$('.resume') .hide()
$('#expe1').show();
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
$('.resume') .hide()
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    $('.resume'+target).toggle();

});
```

Sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzsss98j/)..

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question (showing the first div on load) you could do :

```
$(function() {
    $('.resume').hide()
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.resume') .hide()
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.resume'+target).toggle();
    });
    $("#expe1").toggle();
});
```

Then I'm not sure what you mean by 'makes it be at the top of the page'. Keep in mind that using .hide() actually takes the element out of the flow of the page as far as I know, which means that from your browser's standpoint the hidden div simply do not exists (not rendered at all). So the browser only "sees" one div, and naturally puts it at the top of the page.

**EDIT:**

Jquery's .hide() is equivalent to the css `{display: none}`, which takes the element out of the page (thus the pretty strange layout with divs always being on top of the page). If you want to be able to toggle on/off your divs while keeping the original layout, you can instead use a css class of `{visibility: hidden}` and toggle it on/off when clicked.

**css**

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**html**

```
<a href="#expe1" class="fa fa fa-times closer">Link1</a>
<div class="resume" id="expe1">Open Block 1</div>

<a href="#expe2" class="fa fa fa-times closer">Link2</a>
<div class="resume hidden" id="expe2">Open Block 2</div>

<a href="#expe3" class="fa fa fa-times closer">Link3</a>
<div class="resume hidden" id="expe3">Open Block 3</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($('.resume' + target).hasClass('hidden')) {
      $('.resume' + target).removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('.resume' + target).addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

=> [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uj34d2p1/) <=

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. I would keep it simple. 

1.Change the href links to spans. This will keep the page from flying around.
2. Use css to hide all .resume classes.
3. Make the target of the toggle the next closest .resume so you can get rid of some of the id in you code.
4. Before your click function show the first instance of .resume class.
5. I added a .container div just for house keeping. You dont need it.

```js
$('.resume:first').show(); // show first occurance of the .resume

$('.closer').on('click', function() {
  
  $('.resume').hide(); // clear all .resume classes
  
  var target = $(this).next(".resume"); // get the next div nearest the link.

  $(target).toggle(); // toggle the closest div

});
```

```css
.resume {
  display: none;
}

.closer {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  background: #888888;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  background: #CCC;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1c5ea170a0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <span class="fa fa fa-times closer">Link1</span>
  <div class="resume">Open Block 1<br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tortor amet dui vestibulum wisi pellentesque, ipsum fusce suspendisse sed. Donec elit dolor elit adipiscing nec ornare, convallis non non in rutrum pede, et etiam dignissim pellentesque etiam, leo phasellus metus. Id habitant ullamcorper, pede vehicula quisque maecenas pede, ultricies lectus.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="fa fa fa-times closer">Link2</span>
  <div class="resume">Open Block 2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="fa fa fa-times closer">Link3</span>
  <div class="resume">Open Block 3<br>
     Penatibus tellus non, volutpat lectus ac vitae, tempus expedita vitae nec, suspendisse nonummy eget tellus pretium penatibus. Neque a. Erat tellus eu sit, praesent donec per quis rutrum, placerat neque laoreet. Quisque nascetur est hymenaeos sagittis, mauris id, odio convallis sem amet, penatibus ligula natoque pede, nunc pellentesque in turpis quis leo mus.
  </div>
</div>
```